# localstack testcontainer startup script

Tags: testcontainers, localstack, junit-jupiter

I'm trying to use localstack testContainer to create an S3 and SQS localy.

Here is my code to create the test container :

```
    @Container
static LocalStackContainer localStack =
        new LocalStackContainer(DockerImageName.parse("localstack/localstack"))
                .withClasspathResourceMapping("./localstack_bootstrap/sqs_bootstrap.sh",
                        "/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/sqs_bootstrap.sh", BindMode.READ_ONLY)
                .withServices(SQS)
                .withServices(S3)
                .waitingFor(Wait.forLogMessage("Initialized.", 1));
```

i tryied also with this configuration :

```
 .withClasspathResourceMapping("./localstack_bootstrap",
                        "/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d/", BindMode.READ_ONLY)
```

And here is the script i use to create localstack stuff :

```
c/test/resources/localstack/init.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "start creating queue"
awslocal sqs create-queue --queue-name test-order-queue
echo "Initialized."
```

But it seems the script is not executed so i think i'm doing something wrong but i'm not able to figure out it.

ANy help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try using the `.withFileSystemBind(hostPath, containerPath)` method.
The key difference is that the classpath is a runtime concept that helps the JVM find classes and resources, while the file system is where your actual files are stored.
Here's a working [example](https://github.com/tinyg210/stack-bytes-apigw-lambda-s3/blob/main/github-actions-testcontainers/src/test/java/apigw/LocalStackConfig.java). Make sure you keep the `/etc/localstack/init/ready.d` container path. That's where init hooks go in the ready phase: https://docs.localstack.cloud/references/init-hooks/.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thx you, that is working like a charm since i'm using '''.withFileSystemBind(hostPath, containerPath)''', and the "/etc/localstack/init/ready.d" path